# Timezone using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-api, timezone

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/xml?sensor=false&timestamp=1477353600&location=0,0

This URL doesnot return timezone for some latitudes and longitudes.

Sample (latitude,longitude)values that does not have timezone:
0,0
27.6836,-80
26.1513,-97
33.1666,138.1
6.2666,112

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro):

> Note that time zone data may not be available for locations over water, such as oceans or seas.

All the locations you gave are over water.